# Microsoft Access Record Corruption

Tags: ms-access

I'm having another issue with an Microsoft Access database. Every so often, some records will get corrupted. Something happens and different shapes, Chinese characters, and wrong data will be in the records. I did find a way on not losing the corrupted records by having a backup for that table that I update everyday. Still, it's a bit of an annoyance especially when an update is ran.

I've tried to look for different solutions for this problem but none have really worked. It's a database that can be used by multiple users at the same time. It's an older one that I've had to update a bit. I don't have any memo fields present in the table either.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an autonumber field as a primary key, that could cause an increased corruption risk if the autonumber seed is reset and begins duplicating existing values. [This has since been fixed, but you may need to update your Jet Engine Service Pack](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291162)

If you are in a multi-user environment and have not split your database, you should try that. You can split the database using the database tools tab on the ribbon in the "Move Data" section. That can reduce corruption risk by better managing concurrent updates to the same record. [See further discussion here.](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-plus-reasons-to-split-an-access-database/)

Unfortunately I can't tell you the problem without more information regarding your tables and relationships. If the corruption is a common result of your update query, I would start by looking through your update routine for errors.

Comment: The "autonumber" article you linked is really bad. It doesn't say that AutoNumber PKs increase corruption risk, only that they may make recovery from corruption more difficult. Even that is doubtful, and the suggested workaround is borderline insane. -- Even in 2002, Access wasn't so corruption-prone to warrant this.

Comment: But +1 for splitting the database!

Comment: Good point, that article wasn't great. What I do want to highlight is that an autonumber can cause corruption if its "Seed" is reset. This was a known issue in Access 2003, and as OP states this was an old system. If it gets reset it can begin throwing duplicate values that already exist in your table, causing corruption (though maybe only is it's a primary key?). I have had personal experience with this happening at work, and I just needed to update the service pack for the Jet engine. [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291162)

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe I don't want to remember these days. :) Perhaps add that info to your answer.

Comment: Some of us can never forget. :) Thanks for the feedback!